# Including tools in pyproject.toml

Tags: python-3.x, cicd

I have included checks of formatters and linters (like black and ruff) in pre-commit and I have also included pre-commit as part of my cicd pipeline.

But I have also seen, people include such checks in their `pyproject.toml` file (for example: [here](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/blob/master/pyproject.toml)), the `tool.mypy` and `tool.ruff` section. My question, is it beneficial to include these tools in `pyproject.toml` also, or there is no advantage to include them if they are already part of one's ci/cd pipeline.

Comment: I think there's a false dichotomy somewhere here. `pyproject.toml` is just the config file. If you need to configure how those tools behave, you can use their tables `pyproject.toml`.

Comment: So when I add a tool like `ruff` using `tool.ruff`, when is it that tool used? I am assuming, it's when I run `python build` command. Or using pyproject.toml i can generally configure these tools behaviour, by generally I mean configuring for IDEs etc etc.